# setting up Emacs for HOL4

Tags: emacs, theorem-proving, hol

I am a newbie of both HOL4 and Emacs. Apologize for the probably silly question.

I wish to set up Emacs for HOL4 following the instruction from https://hol-theorem-prover.org/HOL-interaction.pdf. I tried to start HOL process on Emacs with `Alt-h h` and pressed `Enter`, but Emacs returns `Symbol’s function definition is void: if-let*`. My `.emacs.d/init.el` is defined as follows. What should I do to fix the error? Thanks.

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)
(transient-mark-mode 1)
(load "/home/user/HOL/tools/hol-mode")
(load "/home/user/HOL/tools/hol-unicode")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Symbol’s function definition is void: if-let*" means the called function `if-let*` is not available (not "pre-loaded") at the moment of its call. Since you wrote this happened when you "tried to start HOL process", most probably this function was called by the `HOL` library.

In order to find where the function definition is located, type `C-h f <if-let*>` (command `M-x describe-function`) <sup>1</sup>. In my setup, the output starts with the following line:

```
if-let* is a Lisp macro in ‘subr-x.el’
```

This means `if-let*` is defined in the file `subr-x.el` (it exposes the library `subr-x`). The commentary section of this library says:

> If you want to use this library, it's almost always correct to use:
>
> (eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))

Hence adding the following line to the `.emacs.d/init.el` before loading `HOL` library should fix the issue:

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))
```

[Though it's common to load libraries with just `(require '<library-name>)`.]

Note that the exact location of a function may depend on the GNU Emacs version and/or other specifics of a setup. Without this information at hand, this answer tries to explain how to approach the issue in a general way. (When asking a question it's advisable to specify the version of GNU Emacs and provide reproduction steps calling Emacs without user configurations: `emacs -Q`.)

---

1. [Emacs Key Notation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsKeyNotation)